# wechat access_token: invalid appid (error 40013)

Tags: wechat

Maybe it's pretty dumb question, but I'm really lost.

Doc describes everything pretty simple: http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Startup#AppId_and_AppSecret

I created account (at Chinese developer platform), I can log in and see my id and secret:
[image]

So I'm trying to use them to [get access token](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Startup#access_token)

But what I get is this:

```
{
  "errcode": 40013,
  "errmsg": "invalid appid hint: [asR07773612]"
}
```

I don't understand what else should I do to make it work. My official credentials just don't work.

Please help, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your appId is wrong, I was also facing the similar issue for this if you are using a sandbox account or test account of wechat and translating it to English than first it changes the first word of appId to caps. So change it back to small and it worked for me.

After translation:

AppId: `W*******************`

But Actually, the App Id is:

AppId: `w*******************`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gods, it really helps!
Thank you so much, I would never guessed that.

Comment: This was an issue for me too. THANK YOU!